# Hiding dataflow options from plain sight

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I use Google cloud dataflow runner with templates, and pass sensitive information to it via pipeline options (eg user name and password). Anyone opening my dataflow job from the dataflow console can clearly see the sensitive information I sent via options, in the side panel. Is there a way to hide these options from appearing ? Thank You .

Comment: One thought might be to change the pipeline to not take sensitive values from parameters but instead use an alternate.  For example, instead of providing username and password as pipeline options, reads these from a GCS file where the file contains the username and password and the file's permissions don't allow read from others.

Comment: Are you able to use a mechanism such as a service account for the service that you are using?

Comment: No, unfortunately, service account is not an option for our use case .

Answer (score 1):

In java you can use the @Hidden annotation on your PipelineOptions eg:

```
    @Hidden
    public interface Options extends PipelineOptions {
        // Add options here you don't want to display in dataflow
    }
```

https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Hidden